# Recursive function refactoring help: occurrences of char in string starting at ith char

Tags: recursion, f#

Just getting into functional programming and F# with the most appropriately titled [Functional Programming Using F#](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107684064). I wrote the following function definition for problem 2.4 but I'm thinking there's most likely a more elegant and/or idiomatic solution:

```
let rec occurrencesFromIth = 
    let bool2int x = if x then 1 else 0
    function
    | str:string, i, _ when i >= str.Length -> 0
    | str, i, ch -> 
        isIthChar (str,i,ch ) |> bool2int |> (+) (occurrencesFromIth (str,i+1,ch ))
```

`isIthChar` is defined as:

```
let isIthChar ( str:string, i, ch ) = str.[i] = ch
```

The actual problem description is:

> Declare the F# function `occFromIth`:
>
> `string * int * char -> int` where
>   `occFromIth(str,i,ch)` = the number of occurrences of character `ch` in positions `j` in the string `str` with `j >= i`.
>
> Hint: the value should be 0 for `i >= size str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple recursive function would be:

```
let rec occFromIth s i ch = 
  if i >= String.length s then 0
  else (if s.[i] = ch then 1 else 0) + occFromIth s (i + 1) ch
```

Comment: Ooh, you can use `String.length` instead of `string.Length` to avoid specifying the type, nice.

Comment: first answer, simpler than mine, and uses recursion which is in the spirit of the current book chapter and exercises so gets the answer check.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that your `isIthChar` function is an overkill: it usually doesn't make sense to write a function that's *that* short.

To write the `occurrencesFromIth` itself, I would use sequence expression to generate the indexes to test and then use `Seq.sumBy` to count the matching characters:

```
let occurrencesFromIth (str : string, start, ch) =
    seq { start .. str.Length - 1 } |>
        Seq.sumBy (fun i -> if str.[i] = ch then 1 else 0)
```

I would prefer to use something like `Seq.count` even more, but there is no such method. You *could* use `Count()` from LINQ, which makes the code shorter, but I guess that is less idiomatic (and means you can't use `|>`):

```
let occurrencesFromIth (str : string, start, ch) =
    let indexes = seq { start .. str.Length - 1 }
    indexes.Count (fun i -> str.[i] = ch)
```

Comment: You could use `Seq.sumBy (fun i -> if str.[i] = ch then 1 else 0)` in place of `fold`.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, that's better, edited in.

Comment: if could check two answers would check this one also. More functional/declarative in my novice opinion. Gotta learn me some Seq but that is in a few more chapters. (The reason for the isIthChar function is that it was the answer to the previous exercise so reuse was implied - but that doesn't matter, your criticism is valid in general)